# Should my Vue.js code have multiple small instances or a single big instance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting with vue.js. My question is about design patterns.

Should I have multiple Vue instances like this one:

```
        var example = new Vue({
          el: '#post-list',
          data: {
            posts: [
              { title: 'Foo' },
              { title: 'Bar' }
            ]
          }
        });

        var example2 = new Vue({
          el: '#post-list2',
          data: {
            posts: [
              { title: 'Foo' },
              { title: 'Bar' }
            ]
          }
        });
```

Or should I try to group my Vue code inside a big #app element like this:

```
        var app= new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            posts1: [
              { title: 'Foo' },
              { title: 'Bar' }
            ],
            posts2: [
              { title: 'Foo' },
              { title: 'Bar' }
            ]
          }
        });
```

I'm looking for code maitenance and performance. What are the advantages of each approach? Is there a better pattern to follow?

Answer (score 0):

For code maitenance, [Single File Component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html), which serves the same purpose as your first code snippet but more engineeringly is suggested, by the way, [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) maybe a tool you need.

For code performance, many instances cost more than one instance. But one flaw cannot obscure the splendor of the jade. Insignificant lose of performance brought maintainability is acceptable.